# Moving UIView within UIImageView's UIImage in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to move one image on base image.

If I am moving that `UIView`, it crosses `UIImageView's` image.

How to restrict `UIView's` move within `UIImageView's` image? It should supports for square and rectangle. Moving view should not cross its border.

Kindly guide me.

In the screen shots, `UIImageView` background color is black color. 
Moving `UIView` is in white color. White color view is crossing its image [Screen Shot 2]. How to restrict within the image ?

**Code:**

```
 @IBAction func panAcn(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == .Began || sender.state == .Changed {

        let translation = sender.translationInView(self.myImgVw)
        // note: 'view' is optional and need to be unwrapped
        sender.view!.center = CGPointMake(sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPointMake(0,0), inView: self.myImgVw)
    }
 }
```

**Need Output:**

[image]

**My Output**

[image]

Comment: add UIView on UIImageView and show some code.

Comment: Is the UIView a subview of the UIImageView?

Comment: No.. UIView is seperate.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
 @IBAction func panAcn(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == .Began || sender.state == .Changed {

        let translation = sender.translationInView(self.myImgVw)
        // note: 'view' is optional and need to be unwrapped
        guard let view = sender.view else { return }
        var newFrame = view.frame
        newFrame.origin.x = max(self.myImgVw.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.x + translation.y)  
        newFrame.origin.y = max(self.myImgVw.frame.origin.y, view.frame.origin.y + translation.y)
        view.frame = newFrame        
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not Working @bobby

Comment: Need to move view inside imageview's view